# Eclipse Maven build package

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-3

I have a java project that is being built with Maven. Instead of generating the packages from the command line with "mvn package", I would like to generate them from Eclipse.  Looking at the Project->Properties->Maven->Life Cycle mappings, I see that plugin execution for "war:war" within the lifecyle phase "package" is "ignored" and the source is "uninteresting". Where is this data maintained? How do I change it? I tried the obvious, double or right clicking on this war:war and package nodes in Eclipse.

I see lifecycle-mapping-metadata.xml. But, I see no mention of package or war in here.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click the project in Eclipse, **Run As...**, **Maven Package** (or **Maven Build...** and then specify the package goal). That will perform the same operation right in Eclipse, using its embedded Maven runtime.

Comment: I see that now. There is no package, but, there is a build.  I assume build does the package?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a Maven Run Configuration (assuming you have the eclipse maven plugin installed e.g m2e) and define the goals you want to run from there. Once done, this configuration will be available to use as it will now be part of your workspace metadata.